# How to save a photograph to MySQL from GWTUpload SingleUploader?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am using Eclipse Juno and GWTUpload SingleUploader to select and display a photograph. There are a few minor issues however the next major thing to do is save the input to MySQL. So how do I now pass the photograph to MySQL. What I plan to do is store the photograph in a temp folder, pick it up from the temp folder when writing to the DB and then delete the photograph from the temp folder (clean up). I have the following code (copied from step 7 of https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted) on the server side however I have two issues in that I have been unable to resolve.

```
/**
   * Get the content of an uploaded file.
   */
  @Override
  public void getUploadedFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String fieldName = request.getParameter(UConsts.PARAM_SHOW);
    File f = receivedFiles.get(fieldName);
    if (f != null) {
      response.setContentType(receivedContentTypes.get(fieldName));
      FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
      copyFromInputStreamToOutputStream(is, response.getOutputStream());
    } else {
      renderXmlResponse(request, response, XML_ERROR_ITEM_NOT_FOUND);
   }
  }
```

The first issue is at line "String fieldName = request.getParameter(UConsts.PARAM_SHOW);" where I get the error "UConsts cannot be resolved to a variable" my options are: create constant, create class, create interface, create local variable, create field, create enum, create parameter, fix project setup.

The second issue is at line "renderXmlResponse(request, response, XML_ERROR_ITEM_NOT_FOUND);" where I get the error "XML_ERROR_ITEM_NOT_FOUND cannot be resolved to a variable" my options are: create constant, create local variable, create field, create parameter, and some change options which I doubt are the answer as this is proven code from the author.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Regards, Glyn

Answer (score 0):

Is it your project requirement to save the image to DB?

Another approach might be saving the image file to the local file system and storing the full path of the file in DB. This will save from heavy database.

Comment: Hi pundit, yes the project requirement is to save the image to DB. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: I have received advice to import gwtupload.shared.UConsts in my class for the first error. This did not reslove the error. I was also advised to make sure that my servlet was extending gwtupload.server.UploadAction. Which it is. I have the line "public class MyCustomisedUploadServelet extends UploadAction {", as per the original code (https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted). Regards, Glyn

Comment: I resolved the first issue by including the gwtupload jar library to my classpath. It is available here - https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/Downloads?tm=2.
So I only have the second issue outstanding.

Comment: I resolved the second issue by including "protected static final String XML_ERROR_ITEM_NOT_FOUND = "<" + TAG_ERROR + ">item not found</" + TAG_ERROR + ">";". I found this in some similar code using google. Regards, Glyn