# Error trying to write an image defined as PreloadedImage to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, gwt

I am using Eclipse Juno, GWT, Java.
I am trying to upload a photograph to a MySQL database (I get the image using GWTUpload SingleUpload). At my previous post ([How to save a photograph to MySQL from GWTUpload SingleUploader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165873/how-to-save-a-photograph-to-mysql-from-gwtupload-singleuploader)) I was trying to convert the image to byte prior to uploading. I was then told that I can upload directly. So I changed the code and following the GWT recommendations I ended up with defining the variable as "PreloadedImage photograph = new PreloadedImage();". However, the page does not load any more and I get the following errors.

[Errors and view removed to allow more code to be added]

The relevant Server side code:

```
public YthMmbrSectDtls createYouthMember(String youthMemberId,
        String surname, String firstname, java.sql.Date dob,
        PreloadedImage photograph, java.sql.Date archived, String sectionDetailsId,
        String section, String pack, java.sql.Date startDate,
        java.sql.Date endDate) {

    YthMmbrSectDtls ythMmbrSectDtls = null; // necessary unless you do something in the exception handler
    ResultSet result = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(
          "INSERT INTO at_cub_details at_section_details" +
                  " (cd_surname, cd_first_name, cd_dob, cd_photograph, cd_archived," +
                  " sd_section, sd_pack, sd_start_date, sd_end_date) " +
                  "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
      ps.setString(1, surname);
      ps.setString(2, firstname);
      ps.setBlob(3, (java.sql.Blob) photograph);
      ps.setDate(4, (java.sql.Date) dob);
      ps.setDate(5, (java.sql.Date) archived);
      ps.setString(6, section);
      ps.setString(7, pack);
      ps.setDate(8, (java.sql.Date) startDate);
      ps.setDate(9, (java.sql.Date) endDate);
      ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      //do stuff on fail
        System.out.println("SQLException createYouthMember 1.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        user = null;
    }
    finally {
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                result.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException createYouthMember 2.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            }   
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException createYouthMember 3.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
return ythMmbrSectDtls;
}
```

DBConnection class

```
package org.AwardTracker.server;

import gwtupload.client.PreloadedImage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.Base64Utils;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;

import org.AwardTracker.client.BCrypt;
import org.AwardTracker.client.Base64Decode;
import org.AwardTracker.client.DBConnection;
import org.AwardTracker.client.SectionDetails;
import org.AwardTracker.client.User;
import org.AwardTracker.client.YouthMember;
import org.AwardTracker.client.YthMmbrSectDtls;
import org.AwardTracker.server.Base64Encode;
import org.AwardTracker.server.Base64Encode2;



public class MySQLConnection extends RemoteServiceServlet implements DBConnection {
private Connection conn = null;
private String status;
private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/awardtracker";
private String user = "ss";
private String pass = "ss";
public MySQLConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //NEVER catch exceptions like this

        System.out.println("Error connecting to database - not good eh");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public User authenticateUser(String userName, String pass, String level1, java.sql.Date archived1) {
    User user = null; // necessary unless you do something in the exception handler
    ResultSet result = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String stored_hash = null;
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(
          "select * from at_accounts where acc_email_address = \"" + userName  + "\"");
      result = ps.executeQuery();
      while (result.next()) {
         user = new User(result.getString(1), result.getString(2), result.getString(3), null);
         stored_hash = result.getString(3);
      }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      //do stuff on fail
        System.out.println("SQLException authenticateUser 1.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                result.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException authenticateUser 2.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            }   
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException authenticateUser 3.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    if (BCrypt.checkpw(pass, stored_hash))  {
    } else {
        user = null;
    }
    return user;
}

public User duplicateUser(String userName, String pass, String level1, java.sql.Date archived1) {
    User user = null; // necessary unless you do something in the exception handler
    ResultSet result = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(
          "select * from at_accounts where acc_email_address = \"" + userName  + "\"");
      result = ps.executeQuery();
      while (result.next()) {
         user = new User(result.getString(1), null, null, null);
      }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      //do stuff on fail
        System.out.println("SQLException duplicateUser 1.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                result.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException duplicateUser 2.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            }   
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException duplicateUser 3.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
return user;
}

public User createUser(String userName, String pass, String level1, java.sql.Date archived1) {
    User user = null; // necessary unless you do something in the exception handler
    ResultSet result = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String pw_hash = BCrypt.hashpw(pass, BCrypt.gensalt());
    try {
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(
          "INSERT INTO at_accounts (acc_email_address, acc_password) " +
                  "VALUES (?, ?)");
      ps.setString(1, userName);
      ps.setString(2, pw_hash);
      ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      //do stuff on fail
        System.out.println("SQLException createUser 1.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        user = null;
    }
    finally {
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                result.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException createUser 2.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            }   
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException createUser 3.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
return user;
}

public List<YouthMember> getYM(String id, String surname, String first_name, java.sql.Date dob, String photograph, java.sql.Date archived, String pack) {
    List<YouthMember> youthMemberList = new ArrayList<YouthMember>();
    //YouthMember youthMember = null; // necessary unless you do something in the exception handler
    ResultSet result = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String imageString = null;

    try {
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(
      "SELECT at_cub_details.*" +
        " FROM at_cub_details, at_section_details" + 
        " WHERE (at_cub_details.cd_id = at_section_details.cd_id" +
            " AND at_section_details.sd_pack = \"" + pack + "\"" + ")");

      result = ps.executeQuery();
      while (result.next()) {
          imageString = getImageData(result.getString(1));
          YouthMember youthMember = new YouthMember(result.getString(1), result.getString(2), result.getString(3), result.getDate(4), imageString, result.getDate(6));
          youthMemberList.add(youthMember);
      }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      //do stuff on fail
        System.out.println("SQLException getYouthMember 1.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                result.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException getYouthMember 2.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            }   
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException getYouthMember 3.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
return youthMemberList;
}

public String getImageData(String id){
    ResultSet result = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String imageDataString = null;
    String base64 = null;
    try {
        // Read in the image from the database.
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(
              "SELECT at_cub_details.cd_photograph " +
                      "FROM at_cub_details " + 
                      "WHERE at_cub_details.cd_id = \"" + id + "\"");
        result = ps.executeQuery();
        while (result.next()) {
            java.sql.Blob imageBlob = result.getBlob(1);
            byte[] imageData = imageBlob.getBytes(1, (int) imageBlob.length());

            //Convert Image byte array into Base64 String
            imageDataString = encodeImage(imageData);
            imageDataString = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+imageDataString;
        }

    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      //do stuff on fail
        System.out.println("SQLException getImageData 1.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        user = null;
    }
    finally {
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                result.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException getImageData 2.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            }   
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException getImageData 3.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return imageDataString;
}
 /**
  * Encodes the byte array into base64 string
  * @param imageByteArray - byte array
  * @return String a {@link java.lang.String}
  */
public static String encodeImage(byte[] imageByteArray) {
    return Base64Encode2.encode(imageByteArray);
}

public YthMmbrSectDtls createYouthMember(String youthMemberId,
        String surname, String firstname, Date dob,
        String password, Date archived, String sectionDetailsId,
        String section, String pack, Date startDate, Date endDate) {

    YthMmbrSectDtls ythMmbrSectDtls = null; // necessary unless you do something in the exception handler
    ResultSet result = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(
          "INSERT INTO at_cub_details at_section_details" +
                  " (cd_surname, cd_first_name, cd_dob, cd_archived," +
                  " sd_section, sd_pack, sd_start_date, sd_end_date) " +
                  "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
      ps.setString(1, surname);
      ps.setString(2, firstname);
      ps.setDate(3, (java.sql.Date) dob);
      ps.setDate(4, (java.sql.Date) archived);
      ps.setString(5, section);
      ps.setString(6, pack);
      ps.setDate(7, (java.sql.Date) startDate);
      ps.setDate(8, (java.sql.Date) endDate);
      ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      //do stuff on fail
        System.out.println("SQLException createYouthMember 1.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        user = null;
    }
    finally {
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                result.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException createYouthMember 2.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            }   
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException createYouthMember 3.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
return ythMmbrSectDtls;
}

public YthMmbrSectDtls updateYouthMember(String id, String surname,
        String firstname, java.sql.Date dob, java.sql.Date archived,
        String section, String pack, java.sql.Date startDate,
        java.sql.Date endDate) {
    YthMmbrSectDtls ythMmbrSectDtls = null; // necessary unless you do something in the exception handler
    ResultSet result = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try {
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(
              "UPDATE at_cub_details at_section_details" +
                      " (cd_surname, cd_first_name, cd_dob, cd_archived," +
                      " sd_section, sd_pack, sd_start_date, sd_end_date) " +
                      "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
          ps.setString(1, surname);
          ps.setString(2, firstname);
          ps.setDate(3, (java.sql.Date) dob);
          ps.setDate(4, (java.sql.Date) archived);
          ps.setString(5, section);
          ps.setString(6, pack);
          ps.setDate(7, (java.sql.Date) startDate);
          ps.setDate(8, (java.sql.Date) endDate);
          ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      //do stuff on fail
        System.out.println("SQLException updateYouthMember 1.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        user = null;
    }
    finally {
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                result.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException updateYouthMember 2.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            }   
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException updateYouthMember 3.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
return ythMmbrSectDtls;
}

public YouthMember readYM(String id, String surname, String first_name, java.sql.Date dob, String photograph, java.sql.Date archived) {
    YouthMember youthMemberDetails = null; // necessary unless you do something in the exception handler
    ResultSet result = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String imageString = null;
    System.out.println("ID received = " + id);
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(
            "SELECT * " + 
            "FROM at_cub_details " +
            "WHERE at_cub_details.cd_id = \"" + id + "\"");
//          ps.getString(1, id);
//              "SELECT * " +
//              " FROM at_cub_details");
//              " FROM at_cub_details " + 
//              " WHERE at_cub_details.cd_id = 2");
//              " WHERE at_cub_details.cd_id = \"" + id + "\"");
      result = ps.executeQuery();

      while (result.next()) {
          imageString = getImageData(result.getString(1));
          youthMemberDetails = new YouthMember(result.getString(1), result.getString(2), result.getString(3), result.getDate(4), imageString, result.getDate(6));
      }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      //do stuff on fail
        System.out.println("SQLException readYM 1.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                result.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException readYM 2.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            }   
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException readYM 3.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return youthMemberDetails;
}

public SectionDetails invested(String id, String youth_member_id,
        String section, String pack, java.sql.Date start_date,
        java.sql.Date end_date) {
    SectionDetails sectionDetails = null; // necessary unless you do something in the exception handler
    ResultSet result = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(
          "SELECT MIN(start_date)" +
          "FROM at_section_details" +
          "WHERE cd_id = \"" + youth_member_id  + "\"" +
                "AND cd_pack = \"" + pack + "\"");
      result = ps.executeQuery();
      while (result.next()) {
         sectionDetails = new SectionDetails(null, null, null, null, result.getDate(5), null);
      }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      //do stuff on fail
        System.out.println("SQLException invested 1.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                result.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException invested 2.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            }   
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException invested 3.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return sectionDetails;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use classes in rpc-calls which are not serializables.

Remove your references to `PreloadedImage` in `org.AwardTracker.client.DBConnection`.

Related with:

`I was trying to convert the image to byte prior to uploading`

You cannot do this in client side, so upload your image and do whatever you want in server side. Then ask for the original or modified image from the ui creating `Image` widgets or using the gwtupload's `PreloadedImage` helper.

Note: that using HTML5, you can do certain things in client side, like read the image from filesystem, write it in a canvas, manipulate it in the canvas, read it in base64 and send the content to the server, etc. But that only works in certain browsers.

Comment: Hi Manolo, for paragraphs 1 and 3 do you mean I can not use PreloadImage on the Client side (i.e., "PreloadedImage photograph = new PreloadedImage();" is invalid)? Then in paragraph 2 do you mean remove the line "rpc = (DBConnectionAsync) GWT.create(DBConnection.class);
  ServiceDefTarget target = (ServiceDefTarget) rpc;
  String moduleRelativeURL = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "MySQLConnection";
  target.setServiceEntryPoint(moduleRelativeURL);"? Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the DBConnection was a server class (the name is a bit confusing). Actually you dont have to remove it because it is your rpc, but probably remove a non serializable referenced anywhere. Could you post the code of DBConnection?

Comment: PreloadImage is a client class, it is thought for UI and it is not serializable, so you cannot use it in RPC methods nor in serializable objects.

Comment: Hi Manolo, thank you for the explanation in relation to PreloadImage; this makes it clearer. I have already made changes to DBConnection trying to get this to work. However, I have attached the latest version if this helps. To make this less confusing what naming standard should I use? Thanks for your help, Glyn.

Comment: For some reason you are importing many client-only classes in your servlet, although luckly it could work. Normally in client you dont import classes like PreloadImage nor Window (take a look to namespaces having the client word). When client and server share classes by convention they are placed in a 'shared' namespace.

Comment: To me DBConnection or MySQLConnection suggest a connection with the ddbb, but actually yours is a RPC services classes. I would name them to MyRpcService MyRpcServiceAsync and MyRpcServiceImpl where My could be replace by something meaningful for your organization.

Comment: Hi Manolo, A number of the imports are not used. I have been reticent to delete them because every time I clean up I manage to break something. However, I am learning a little (very little) more each day and so I am brave enough now to make a copy and clean up. I will also make your suggested name changes as I believe this can be done via a global rename. Again, I will take a copy first and take it one step at a time. I greatly appreciate your help. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Hi Manolo, I resolved this by using the servelet in step 7 of your ecample https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted, returning the path of where the servelet stored it, sending the path to the server side and writing using File imgfile = new File (photograph); FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imgfile); ps.setBinaryStream(4, fis, (int) imgfile.length()); where photograph is the path to the image. All I need to do now is delete the temporary image. Thanks for all your help. Regards, Glyn.